# How to pass shortcode param value to Javascript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a contact form shortcode that I process with ajax. The shortcode have a parameter to set the email address in which the messages are going to be sent. This way I can use differents email accounts to receive the messages depending on what form is.

When you clic submmit this javascript take the form fields value with `$('#name').val()` and send to the `ajax_contact_form` function I created in another php file:

```
 $('.contact-form').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();
    $('#submit')
      .after('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x"></i>')
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.post(
      action,
      {
        action: 'ajax_contact_form',
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        message: $('#message').val(),
      },
      function(data){
        document.getElementById('form-alert').innerHTML = data;
        $('#form-alert').slideDown('slow');
        $('.contact-form .fa-spin').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        if(data.match('success') != null) $('.contact-form').slideUp('slow');
      }
    );
  });
  return false;
  });
```

I can do the same for the email address, print in the html code like this: `data-email="xxxx@xxx.com"`, but obviously I don't want to put the email address printed in the HTML code. And I don't know another way to achieve this.

How can I pass the shortcode param value to the ajax php file without printing in the form?

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
$('.contact-form').serialize()
```

Does it help? If this isn't what you wanted, could you explain it a bit more?

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/